# What is the name of this rule

Tags: causative-get

They are both the same to me. What is the difference?

For example:

- "I'm getting bored tonight"-"I'm boring tonight"
- "I'm getting came"-"I'm Coming"

English is not my first language - If you point out my mistakes I'd be very grateful..
I want to improve my English and I don't want to use translate anymore.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Astralbee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- "Bored" can be a verb (past tense of *to bore*) or a noun (the state of boredom).
- "Boring" can be the present participle of the verb *to bore*, or it can be an adjective to describe something that causes boredom.

So, context is everything.

"I am bored" means you are in a state of boredom. It is *you* who is bored.

"I am boring" means you *cause* boredom. You bore others.

---

"Getting came" is not grammatically correct at all, for at least two reasons.

"Come" is a *verb*. "Coming" is the present participle / gerund of the same verb. So you can't just change the words unless you intend to change the tense, in which case the rest of the sentence would change also.

Secondly, you don't "get" a verb. *To get* is a verb in itself.

"I'm coming" means you are presently moving or travelling towards the person you are speaking to. The past tense would be "I came".

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
Is what I understand right?
I add "Getting" to translate "Bored" to verb.
So if "bored" was a verb, I could add "ing". (Boring)

Comment: I cannot use "Getting" because "Come" is a verb. "Ing" is enough to translate it to present continuous tense.

Comment: @ÖmürTokman I've added some detail to my answer, hopefully this explains it.